# Take a screenshot of Qt application in fullscreen, undex X11

Tags: c++, qt, x11

I have the following setup: a linux box that, after booting, launches a C++ Qt (with lots of QQuick components) application in kiosk mode. That is, the application runs in fullscreen without any window decorations or frame.

For testing purposes, I injected the application with a shared library, which exposes testings functionalities like inspecting Qt objects and taking full screen screenshots.

If the application is **not** running in full screen, I can take screenshots without any problems. However, in full screen all I get pictures with all black pixels.

As an alternative, I tried:

- scrot
- xwd, using xwininfo to identify the window
- import, from the imagemagick tool suite

None of these worked. With the application running in fullscreen, the resulting screenshots are all black.

So I suspect that the problem is on the X11 side, but I am lost on how to solve this.

How can I take a screenshot of an application running in fullscreen, under X11 ?  Could Qt be part of the problem ?

Comment: Maybe it does some completely direct rendering. Try to find in the Desktop Environment settings or maybe inn the video drivers settings something like 'always do indirect rendering'. Other option is to use the `grabImage()` function of the root item.

Comment: @Velkan: I can't (or better, prefer not to) touch the environment settings because I want the testing apparatus to be minimally intrusive. Where is the grabImage() function , in XLib or in Qt ?

Comment: It's in Qt QtQuick: http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtquick-item.html#grabToImage-method

Comment: Thanks, I will try using QtQuick to take screenshots. Now I was using a QScreen object

Comment: Ok, it worked using QtQuick instead of a "normal" Qt object. I guess it had something to do with how Qt is being rendered in fullscreen. I would like to mark Velkan's answer as correct, but I don't know how to do it for a comentary.